# How to simplify this Java code?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, simplify

I'm writing some Java code for a Minecraft server software called Spigot (spigotmc.org) and I've just written this. The goal is to check each side of the variable `block` and check for a wall sign as you can see. It should only need to find one. Then it will update it and whatnot. I know this code can be simplified, but for the moment I can't see how without making an entire new function for the code inside the conditionals, which I don't want to do. Is there a better way to write this conditional?

```
// Get an attached sign
Block sign;
if ((sign = block.getRelative(BlockFace.NORTH)).getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN) {
    org.bukkit.block.Sign data = (Sign) sign.getState();
    data.setLine(1, "OFF");
    data.update();
} else if ((sign = block.getRelative(BlockFace.EAST)).getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN) {
    org.bukkit.block.Sign data = (Sign) sign.getState();
    data.setLine(1, "OFF");
    data.update();
} else if ((sign = block.getRelative(BlockFace.WEST)).getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN) {
    org.bukkit.block.Sign data = (Sign) sign.getState();
    data.setLine(1, "OFF");
    data.update();
} else if ((sign = block.getRelative(BlockFace.SOUTH)).getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN) {
    org.bukkit.block.Sign data = (Sign) sign.getState();
    data.setLine(1, "OFF");
    data.update();
}
```

Comment: If your code ***is working*** and you are simply asking for better/simpler way to implement it then you should ask this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah, i'm "pretty sure" it works. :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner if scopes always the same, so you can use "or" command between the conditions:

```
// Get an attached sign
Block sign;
if (((sign = block.getRelative(BlockFace.NORTH)).getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN) 
 || ((sign = block.getRelative(BlockFace.EAST)).getType()  == Material.WALL_SIGN)
 || ((sign = block.getRelative(BlockFace.WEST)).getType()  == Material.WALL_SIGN)
 || ((sign = block.getRelative(BlockFace.SOUTH)).getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN)
    org.bukkit.block.Sign data = (Sign) sign.getState();
    data.setLine(1, "OFF");
    data.update();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like what I'm aiming for!

Comment: Although this code is logically equivalent to OPs, it is not immediately clear, because short-circuit evaluation comes into play. It is very important that the assignments to `sign` stopped immediately after the first successful match; otherwise, the `sign` would end up wit a wrong value.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, you are right, but on this case it will work same as before

Comment: @RoyShmuli Yes, it will. Since OP's code looks like something written by a relative newcomer (apart from assigning inside an `if`, this is an intermediate-level trick), he might benefit from some more explanation of this specific point.

Comment: This is an example of short-circuiting conditional statements and perfectly valid in Java. The problem I see is there is still quite a bit of code in that if statement!

Comment: Not sure this is best answer IMHO, I would think Aivean's is far superior -1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a loop?

```
// Get an attached sign
Block sign;
BlockFace[] faces = new BlockFace[] {
    BlockFace.NORTH,
    BlockFace.EAST,
    BlockFace.WEST,
    BlockFace.SOUTH};

for(BlockFace face : faces) {
    if ((sign = block.getRelative(face)).getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN) {
        org.bukkit.block.Sign data = (Sign) sign.getState();
        data.setLine(1, "OFF");
        data.update();
        break;
    }
}
```

This approach works well when you have many options to look at. Also, if you are doing similar logic elsewhere, definitely create a function that all clients with same needs can call on!

Answer (score 2):

According to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle you need to reuse repeating parts. In your example the whole if block is the same, except for the face.

1. Replacing ifs with for:

   ```
   List<BlockFace> blockFaces = Arrays.asList(BlockFace.NORTH, BlockFace.EAST, BlockFace.WEST, BlockFace.SOUTH);
   for (BlockFace face : blockFaces) {
       Sign sign = block.getRelative(face);
       if (sign.getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN) {
           org.bukkit.block.Sign data = (Sign) sign.getState();
           data.setLine(1, "OFF");
           data.update();
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Extracting method:

   ```
   private boolean updateAttachedSign(Block block, BlockFace face) {
       Sign sign = block.getRelative(face);
       if (sign.getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN) {
           org.bukkit.block.Sign data = (Sign) sign.getState();
           data.setLine(1, "OFF");
           data.update();
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   {
       boolean signIsUpdated =
           updateAttachedSign(block, BlockFace.NORTH) ||
           updateAttachedSign(block, BlockFace.EAST) ||
           updateAttachedSign(block, BlockFace.WEST) ||
           updateAttachedSign(block, BlockFace.SOUTH);
   }
   ```

The second solution, despite of being superior approach in general, seems to be a bit overcomplicated for your case.  I'd stick with the first one.

*Edit by [@Constantin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2754695/constantin):*

Use short-circuited conditionals prudently. Please refer to this excellent post on where this makes sense https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284415/short-circuit-evaluation-is-it-bad-practice

Comment: +1 for suggesting your second method is superior because it ensures the caller is not doing too much topical logic. The general rule is that each method has a very specific function and not to over extend its workload. A common mistake junior developers have is to create huge monolithic methods that do too much, often replicating code elsewhere again and again because they have failed to keep it modular